# Spring Boot unable to resolve Freemarker view

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, freemarker

I am attempting to get Freemarker views displaying with Spring Boot for the first time, and currently get the following error in the browser:

> Whitelabel Error Page
>
> This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing
>   this as a fallback.
>
> Sun Feb 19 17:59:07 GMT 2017 There was an unexpected error (type=Not
>   Found, status=404). No message available

I am using Spring Boot 1.5.

My file structure:

[image]

LoginController

```
package com.crm.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import com.crm.service.LoginService;

@Controller
public class LoginController {

    @Autowired
    private LoginService loginService;

    @RequestMapping("/login")
    public String authenticate() {
        return "loginPage";
    }
}
```

application.properties

```
spring.freemarker.template-loader-path: /
spring.freemarker.suffix: .ftl
```

Server

```
package com.crm;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Server{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Server.class, args);
    }
}
```

Why is Spring unable to resolve the loginPage.ftl view? Why can't I see it in the web browser?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With Spring Boot 1.5.1, you don't need to add those properties to your application.properties file, they're already defined, thanks to autoconfiguration.

Remove those 2 properties and it should work with the following dependencies in your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-freemarker</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Documentation can be found here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-template-engines

Comment: If you're using spring-security like I use to doing with login pages and Thymeleaf/FreeMarker, make sure you add the @EnableWebSecurity to your configuration, so the resources are resolved correctly

Comment: As explained in the link above. The template engines look in `src/main/resources/templates` not in `src/main/java/resources/templates`.

Answer (score 20):

Spring Boot recently yet again introduced a breaking change, which leads to the infamous `whitelabel error` page. They changed the default suffix from `.ftl` to `.ftlh`.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/15131

So for Spring Boot 2.2.x applications, these extensions have to be updated.

Comment: Also, its possible to change property spring.freemarker.suffix to ".ftl"

Answer (score 3):

Your freemarker template directory settings inside `application.properties` is wrong. It should be:

```
spring.freemarker.template-loader-path=classpath:/templates/
```

Comment: I think you mean `application.properties` file and not `application.xml` file.

Comment: That change hasn't fixed it.

Comment: @crm could you please confirm whether or not your view is getting called?

Comment: @Ashraf.Shk786 The controller method is being called correctly.

Comment: Is there some other configuration required to resolve Freemarker views that I haven't considered?

Comment: i don't think any more configuration is required apart from what @shi suggested.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136088/discussion-between-ashraf-shk786-and-crm).

Answer (score 3):

It started working for me when I returned the template name as the constructor argument to a ModelAndView object from the controller method instead of just a String. Not sure why, but I don't have time to figure it out and was looking for a quick fix. If anyone cares to explain, please do.

Spring boot 2.0.2.RELEASE  with Freemarker. This is the content of application.properties:

```
spring.freemarker.enabled=true
spring.freemarker.template-loader-path=classpath:/templates
```